# c++ pthreads and struct's corrupting data

Tags: c++, multithreading, struct, pthreads

I'm new to pthreads and having a hard time creating a thread with a struct and keeping it's data intact while re-casting it from a void pointer.

I've spent days searching around trying to find a reason for this and haven't had much luck.  Out of my two structures (using two different threads) one re-casts correctly in the thread, but for whatever reason, the second doesn't.

Structs:

```
struct Arguments {
    List linkedList;
    Node node;
    Arguments(){}
    Arguments (List *newList, Node *newNode){
        linkedList = *newList;
        pcb = *newPCB;
    }
};

struct ClockControl {
    int counter = 0;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
};
```

Threads:

```
void *schedule(void *args){

    //Arguments *newArgs = static_cast<Arguments*>(args); <-- Tried this, doesn't work either.
    arguments *newArgs = (arguments *) args;
    List tempList = (newArgs ->linkedList);  //DATA HERE IS CORRUPTED/WRONG
    Node tempNode = (newArgs ->node);  //DATA HERE IS CORRUPTED/WRONG

    cout << "Flagged" << Lendl;

    return NULL;
}

void *clockTime(void *clock){
    //This thread works fine

    clockControl *newClock = (clockControl*) clock;
    int localVariable = 0;

    localVariable = (newClock -> counter);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(newClock -> lock));
    localVariable++;
    newClock->counter = localVariable;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(newClock -> lock));

    return NULL;
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{  
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];  //Defined as 5

    clockControl clock;
    clock.counter = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&clock.lock, NULL);

    //Lists are initialized with variables.    
    List pendingList = initializeList();
    List readyList = initializeList();


    Arguments *args = new Arguments(&readyList, &pendingList.head->info);

    while (clock.counter < 6000){
        pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, clockTime, (void*) &clock);

        if (clock.counter == pendingList.head->info.timeCreated){

            pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, schedule, (void*) &args);
                          //INSPECTING args HERE HAS ACCURATE DATA

    }

        //Clean up threads
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, I've searched around and pretty much spinning my wheels at this point.  I have a suspicion it might be that the memory is being freed or cleaned up prior to the thread getting executed, but I can't find a way around it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks to me like the loop will keep spinning in circles, creating threads. Furthermore, the clock thread updates clock.counter, which the main execution thread reads, without any sequencing whatsoever. This is obvious undefined behavior, and a bug. There are too many problems with the shown code. I suggest that you start with a simpler multithreaded excersize, than this.

Comment: This really looks more like C than C++, except for the `new` keyword...

Comment: @c650 Yeah... the requester specifically asked for pthreads instead of C++'s std::threads, and I inherited the linked list/node code.  Once I get the threads running, the rest of it is getting updated.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's why we learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the address of the pointer to args to your schedule function. When you use `&args`, `args` is already an `Arguments*` so you are passing an `Arguments**`. To solve this you can simply pass `args` by itself to the function.

Also just so you know, `reinterpret_cast<Arguments*>` is probably more appropriate than `static_cast` in this circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines of code should be swapped

```
localVariable = (newClock -> counter);

pthread_mutex_lock(&(newClock -> lock)); z
```

i.e.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&(newClock -> lock));
localVariable = (newClock -> counter);
```

So that `localVariable` will be the right value when more that one thread is reading the `counter` and updating it